# cannot see inputted text in textarea and input fields on iPhone

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on the following site:

http://www.jpdgallery.com/

When you click the hamburger icon in the bottom right corner, a contact form slides over. On chrome on my macbook, the input and textarea fields work fine--in both regular and in mobile view. When I deploy this, and test it on an iphone in chrome and safari in mobile or chrome, I cannot see the text as I am typing. I know that it is still typing though because I receive the text in the form submission.

Because I cannot replicate in development environment, I am having trouble figuring out how to troubleshoot. Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

I have pasted the html and all the CSS which applies to the input elements as extracted from Safari inspector view.

```css
Style Attribute {
}
#first_3, #last_3, #input_4, #input_5 {
font-size: 1.3rem !important;
height: 3.3rem !important;
}
#first_3, #last_3, #input_4, #input_5 {
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
button, input {
overflow: visible;
}
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
margin: 0;
font-family: inherit;
line-height: inherit;
}
html * {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
-webkit-user-select: none;
}
* {
padding: 0;
}
input, input:matches([type="password"], [type="search"]) {
color: text;
background-color: -webkit-control-background;
border-top-width: 2px;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-left-width: 2px;
border-top-style: inset;
border-right-style: inset;
border-bottom-style: inset;
border-left-style: inset;
border-top-color: initial;
border-right-color: initial;
border-bottom-color: initial;
border-left-color: initial;
border-image-source: initial;
border-image-slice: initial;
border-image-width: initial;
border-image-outset: initial;
border-image-repeat: initial;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
cursor: auto;
}

input, textarea, keygen, select, button {
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-variant-caps: normal;
letter-spacing: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
text-transform: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: start;
}
input, textarea, keygen, select, button, meter, progress {
writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}

ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
ul, menu, dir {
display: block;
margin-block-start: 1em;
margin-block-end: 1em;
margin-inline-start: 0px;
margin-inline-end: 0px;
padding-inline-start: 40px;
}
.cd-nav .cd-navigation-wrapper {
height: 100%;
overflow-y: auto;

padding: 40px 5% 40px calc(5% + 40px);
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);

transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);

transform: translateX(-50%);
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.7s;

transition: transform 0.7s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.86, 0.01, 0.77, 0.78);

transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.86, 0.01, 0.77, 0.78);
}


.navigation-is-open .cd-nav {
visibility: visible;
-webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
transition: visibility 0s 0s;
}
.cd-nav {
position: fixed;
z-index: 2000;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #243040;
-webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.7s;
transition: visibility 0s 0.7s;
}

body {
margin: 0;
background-color: #fff;
}
body {
background-color: #ffffff;
}

html, body, .container2 {
width: 100% !important;
height: 100%;
/* max-height: 100%; */
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
body {
background-color: whitesmoke !important;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex: 0 1 auto;
}
:root {
--blue: #007bff;
--indigo: #6610f2;
--purple: #6f42c1;
--pink: #e83e8c;
--red: #dc3545;
--orange: #fd7e14;
--yellow: #ffc107;
--green: #28a745;
--teal: #20c997;
--cyan: #17a2b8;
--white: #fff;
--gray: #6c757d;
--gray-dark: #343a40;
--primary: #007bff;
--secondary: #6c757d;
--success: #28a745;
--info: #17a2b8;
--warning: #ffc107;
--danger: #dc3545;
--light: #f8f9fa;
--dark: #343a40;
--breakpoint-xs: 0;
--breakpoint-sm: 576px;
--breakpoint-md: 768px;
--breakpoint-lg: 992px;
--breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
--font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
--font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;
}
html {
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

html {
display: block;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
box-sizing: border-box;
}


*, ::after, ::before {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
 <form class="jotform-form" action="https://submit.jotform.us/submit/0000000000/" method="post" name="form_00000000000" id="93267152447158" accept-charset="utf-8">
                    <h2>Contact / Order Request Form</h2>
                    <nav class="postform-fields">
                        <ul class="cd-primary-nav slide-over-form">
                            <li>First Name</li>
                            <input type="text" id="first_3" name="q3_name[first]" data-component="first" />
                            <li>Last Name</li>
                            <input type="text" id="last_3" name="q3_name[last]" data-component="last" />
                            <li>Email</li>
                            <input type="email" id="input_4" name="q4_email" data-component="email" />
                            <li>Note</li>
                            <textarea id="input_5" name="q5_typeA" data-component="textarea"></textarea>
                            
                            <div>
                                <button id="input_2" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark form-submit-button" data-component="button">SUBMIT
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="cd-half-block">
                            <address>
                                <ul class="cd-contact-info">
                                    <li><a href="mailto:info@jpdconcepts.com">info@[domain].com</a></li>
                                    <li>[555]-[555]-9211</li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span>VermontUSA</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </address>
                            <!-- .cd-half-block -->
                        </div> <!-- .cd-navigation-wrapper -->
                    </nav>
                </form>
```

Comment: Please don't ask us to go out an check the code on your website. Post the relevant code right here in your question.

Comment: Is that an actual rule you can cite to? I will post the html when I’m back at my desk but I don’t think that will fully convey the situation. There is no relevant code here. There are days of CSS but only the only CSS targeting these elements is discussed here.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not just a place for you to get the answer to your question, it's a knowledge base and will be used by people for years to come. 3rd party sites/links can die over time, making your question meaningless to those who will come across it. This is why we ask that you include all the relevant aspects of your question, right here in your question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ok, @ScottMarcus, thanks for the link. I have pasted enough CSS in here to allow you to see the issue if you go to Safari. Would love your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried assigning a specific font-size and perhaps add some padding?

I tried the page on iOS Safari and yes, the inputs don't show text, but they are also extremely tiny. My theory is that either the font-size is incorrectly inherited from your rule `font-size: inherit;` or it just gets hidden because of the size of the input.

Try making the inputs bigger and define an explicit font-size, try with `font-size: 1rem`.

You should check [this article on REM vs EM vs PX](https://engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/em-vs-rem-vs-px) in order to better define sizes. I checked in console and your inputs have a `font-size: 10px` inherited on Desktop Chrome.

You can also try experimenting with the input's height. Try adding `height: 2rem`.

Another issue could be that normally mobile browsers have a different behavior for inputs. You could try adding this to your inputs definition:

```css
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
```

Also, your `pure-js-slider.css : line 2` adds a strange rule that might be interfering with all the elements' behavior. Try commenting this one or at least removing the `user-select: none` part:

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

I also managed to add some characters, but look how it appears. The yellow ones were from phone information auto complete and the mail one I managed to write m, but the rest of the letters didn't appear.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I just set the live site to 2rem to be sure. Still have the same issue. You're right that I do need to think about using REM more.

Comment: It should be noted that the text is visible when you autocomplete the form.

Comment: I added some more info, I tried the site again on my phone and for some reason with autocomplete from phone data it fills the fields but the input looks cut because of the input size, try adding a specific height too. Also, I managed to write in the e-mail field but only the first letter appeared.

Comment: @JakeDurell were you able to fix it?

Comment: Looks like it was the user-select  css option combined with small fonts and small fields as you suggested.By adjusting those sizes and changing user-select on each field to "text", that seemed to resolve the issue. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Those global css definitions from some third-party scripts can be a pain in the a**.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else who cannot see the input in a `<textarea>` specifically on iPhone, adding the following CSS solved it for me.

```css
textarea {
    /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-touch-callout: auto;
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: auto;
    /* Konqueror HTML */
    -khtml-user-select: auto;
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-user-select: auto;
    /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
    -ms-user-select: auto;
    /* Non-prefixed version, currently supported by Chrome and Opera */
    user-select: auto;
}
```

PS: Most of these likely are not required, but I didn't get a chance to test which one of them it is that does the trick.